# DataAnnotations: Visual Studio does not let to override RequiresValidationContext property

Tags: .net-4.0, data-annotations, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I was trying to implement custom validation attribute by inheriting from `ValidationAttribute` and found strange thing.
My custom attribute requires validation context, so I've looked at the R# decompiled source of ValidationAttribute and saw, that I need override this in my custom attribute class:

```
public virtual bool RequiresValidationContext
{
  get
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now the fun part - Visual Studio 2012 does not let me do that, telling me that there's no such property for override, although when running project, in debug view I can see that property.

Interesting thing is, that in reference path I see:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

But in R# decompiled file is different path:

> Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

So, compiler uses different dll from runtime.
So, I've tried to switch reference dll to the one R# decompiles, but looks like VS2012 is replacing it with it's version anyway, in project file it looks like:

```
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
```

So, no path is saved in project.
Is there any solution to this without manual editing of a project?

Btw, with 4.5 NET it works fine, I mean it sees RequiresValidationContext property as supposed.

Update: As they say, picture is worth thousand words:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple the property RequiresValidationContext was added to ValidationAttribute in [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.requiresvalidationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since you are coding/using/developing with C# 4.0, i suspect that you target .NET Framework 4.0 and in that version the property does [not exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

So you can´t override the property, cause it does not exist.

Comment: I've updated question with screenshot, where it is seen, that target framework is 4.0, and debug view still sees RequiresValidationContext property. Also, both paths of a dll I've mentioned in question direct to 4.0 folders of framework?

Comment: For me it looks like that the Debugger/QuickWatch window uses the wrong Framework version to display values.

Comment: If I decompile C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll I find there RequiresValidationContext property, also decompiler says this file version is 4.0.0, so I'm not so sure, that debugger is wrong.

Comment: Also I can access propery through reflection using attribute.GetType().GetProperty("RequiresValidationContext")

Comment: When i decompile the assembly using dotPeek the property isn´t defined on ValidationAttribute. I´m using Visual Studio 2010 with latest .NET Framework 4.0.